# Excel VBA to reorder rows based on 2 variables

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am trying to order, from most senior downwards, a list of employees based on who their manager is. The tricky part is having all senior persons employees listed before moving on to the next person of the same level. For example see this image:

[image: What I am looking to achieve]

All people reporting to Dick, either directly or indirectly, are listed below him before moving on to Peter - the next person at his level.

So if the table looked like this:

[image: What I am trying to sort]

Is there a VBA that will reorder the table to look like the first example? The table to be reordered may not look like this - it would have to work regardless of who it was wrongly ordered.

Note: The order of people at the same level is unimportant...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is no such "VBA" unless you write a macro yourself. Have you tried something? Post the code, then we can help. You can't expect us to write a full code for you. Also, please post data, not pictures of data.

Answer (score 0):

I love stuff like this. Create an Excel sheet with two tabs, and name one "Input" and one "Output". Copy your example table into the "Input" then just the headers into "Output". Then plug the code below in. This should show you the idea, which is basic recursion. It's fairly horrible to do in VBA, it would be a lot prettier in C.

```
Option Explicit

Dim RawName() As Variant
Dim RawManager() As Variant
Dim RawLevel() As Variant
Dim TopNode As Integer

Sub FncSortHierarchy()

    TopNode = FncPopulateRawHierarchy("A", "B", "C")

    If TopNode <> 0 Then

        Sheets("Output").Select
        FncWritePerson (TopNode)
        FncGetSubordinates (TopNode)

    End If

End Sub

Private Function FncGetSubordinates(indexManager As Integer) As Integer

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim name As String
    Dim manager As String

    manager = RawName(indexManager)

    For i = 1 To UBound(RawName)

        If RawManager(i) = manager Then

            name = RawName(i)
            FncWritePerson (i)
            FncGetSubordinates (i)

        End If

    Next i

End Function

Private Function FncWritePerson(index As Integer)

    Dim nextRow As Integer

    nextRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

    Range("A" & nextRow) = RawName(index)
    Range("B" & nextRow) = RawManager(index)
    Range("C" & nextRow) = RawLevel(index)

End Function

Private Function FncPopulateRawHierarchy(nameCol As String, managerCol As String, levelCol As String) As Integer

    Dim i As Integer

    Sheets("Input").Select
    ReDim RawName(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
    ReDim RawManager(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
    ReDim RawLevel(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)

    For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        RawName(i - 1) = Range(nameCol & i).Value
        RawManager(i - 1) = Range(managerCol & i).Value
        RawLevel(i - 1) = Range(levelCol & i).Value

        If RawManager(i - 1) = "N/A" Then FncPopulateRawHierarchy = i - 1

    Next i

End Function
```